# bash, find files which contain numbers on filename

Tags: bash, find

In bash, I would like to use the command `find` to find files which contain the numbers from 40 to 70 in a certain position like *c43_data.txt*. How is it possible to implement this filter in `find`?

I tried `file . -name "c**_data.txt" | grep 4`, but this is not very nice.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`ls -R | grep -e 'c[4-7][0-9]_data.txt'`

`find` can be used in place of `ls`, obviously.

Comment: Will this not match files that have 71-79 in them?

Comment: Yes, that will match 71-79, and also doesn't give the pathnames of the files.

Comment: by the way, how can one two criterias at the same time? let's say 

ls -R | grep -e 'c[4-7][0-9]_data.txt' AND ls -R | grep -e 'c[1-2][3-
4]_data.txt'   ???

Comment: asdf: grep -e 'c\([4-7][0-9]\|[1-2][3-4]\)_data.txt'

Generally: man egrep

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps something like:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex "./c(([4-6][0-9])|70)_data.txt"
```

This matches 40 - 69, and 70.

You may also use the `iregex` option for case-insensitive matching.

Comment: No, this won't match 41-49, etc.

Comment: `find . -regex "c[4-7][0-9]_data.txt"` - Yours would only match multiples of ten; 40, 50, 60, 70.

Comment: Thanks. I just woke up and I'm a little groggy, obviously. :-)

Comment: regex matches the whole path. if you want to use the alternation , your regextype should change. `find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex "./c([4-6][0-9]|70)_data.txt"`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ls
c40_data.txt  c42_data.txt  c44_data.txt  c70_data.txt  c72_data.txt  c74_data.txt
c41_data.txt  c43_data.txt  c45_data.txt  c71_data.txt  c73_data.txt  c75_data.txt

$ find . -type f \( -name "c[4-6][0-9]_*txt" -o -name "c70_*txt" -o -name "c[1-2][3-4]_*.txt" \) -print
./c43_data.txt
./c41_data.txt
./c45_data.txt
./c70_data.txt
./c40_data.txt
./c44_data.txt
./c42_data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.\*c([3-6][0-9]|70).\*'
```

with the appropriate refinements to limit this to the files you want